# Typesetting plus-minus uncertainties with different upper and lower bounds

Tags: tables, symbols, math-operators

I'm making a data table and need to include my error bars with my data.  `$\pm$` works great if the upper and lower bounds are the same, however, several of my data points has a different upper limit than lower.  In papers I've read, I've seen plenty of uncertainties expressed as plus x minus y stacked on top of one another with the `$\pm$` sign.
Could someone tell me how to typeset such a thing?

I'm using a journal-specific document type (`aastex`) and the `deluxetable` coding.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do you mean something like

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
 $1.23\substack{+0.4 \\ -0.5}$\,pb
\end{document}
```

(I've been [asked about this](https://bitbucket.org/josephwright/siunitx/issue/24/multi-part-uncertainties-for-numbers) for [`siunitx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/siunitx), but have never really worked out what it actually means or a good interface for an 'automated' approach.)

Comment: How about the following interface? `\num[statistical={+0.2,-0.3}, systematic=0.1] 1.24`, with appropriate options to control the output.

Answer (score 2):

How about just using subscripts and superscripts?

```
$3.6^{+1.1}_{-1.4}$
```

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue, but wanted the uncertainties to not extend outside the original text height too much. As with the use of simple super- and subscript:

```
$1.06^{+0.04}_{-0.05}$
```

An alternative (that turned out to be quite useful in tables where vertical spacing is a problem) can be accomplished with raisebox and reducing the fontsize.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
    $1.06${\raisebox{0.5ex}{\tiny$\substack{+0.04 \\ -0.05}$}} or 
    $1.06${\raisebox{0.5ex}{\tiny$^{+0.04}_{-0.05}$}
    as opposed to $1.06^{+0.04}_{-0.05}$
\end{document}
```